# Android: addView and layout method does not work together

Tags: android, layout, view

In Android when I am adding a view object like ImageView to FrameLayout view and then immediately trying to call `layout()` method to `repositioned the added view object` it is not working. **But when I call the layout method alone after some new event e.g. touch event then layout() seems to work.** This also happens when bringToFront() and layout() is used together, layout() does not seems to work together with other method. Is there any reason why is this like this? Also instead of adding view object in the middle of the screen can it be ADDED at some specific location in FrameLayout?

Answer (score 4):

You should NEVER call layout() directly. This is used by the framework only. You must modify the View's layout params (getLayoutParams()) and call requestLayout().

Comment: im setting layout params of my layout but in onCreate but all the childs view gets invisible??

Comment: and what is the best time to set Layout Params??

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout = new frameLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.BOTTOM);
```