# Adding absolute position of the elements in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

We are creating a `View` programmatically in `onCreate` method and trying to set either of the following to that view-

- The `top` and `left` or
- The `bottom` and `right`.

But it's not working. These absolute positions can be relative to the screen or to the parent layout. Here is an example to reproduce the same thing-

`main.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the `MainActivity`, where I am trying `view` programmatically.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main)

        val root = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.root)

        val layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )

        val view = TextView(this)
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams
        view.text = "Test View"
        
        //Applying top and left value in pixels.
        view.top = 100
        view.left = 100

        root.addView(view)

    }
}
```

`top` and `left` values are not getting assign to the view.

We have tried with many other layouts-

- `FrameLayout`
- `LinearLayout`
- `AbsoluteLayout` (deprecated so not considering)

We have also tried to use [`View#layout()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#layout(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) method but it didn't work either.

We have referred to the following articles-

- [How can I dynamically set the position of view in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535648/how-can-i-dynamically-set-the-position-of-view-in-android)
- [Usage of forceLayout(), requestLayout() and invalidate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856180/usage-of-forcelayout-requestlayout-and-invalidate)
- [Android set view position - setY vs setTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796333/android-set-view-position-sety-vs-settop)
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android
- https://mindmajix.com/android/absolute-layout
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html
- [Android: addView and layout method does not work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672846/android-addview-and-layout-method-does-not-work-together)
- [Android-layout does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397499/android-layout-does-not-work-properly)
- [Android Studio does not show layout preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499839/android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview/50828173)
- [Set the absolute position of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view)
- https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.view.View/setBottom

Comment: I have a question that you want to have 100 top-left margin to your `textview` . is it correct?

Comment: @MayurGajra Thank you for the answer. As in web design `top` and `margin-top` work differently. I am expecting the same behavior here. When I get data to generate a design for android `margin` and `position (top, bottom, left, right)` both are treated differently.